# Flask_restx @api.route return statement results in a TypeError

Tags: flask, flask-restplus, jsonify

I have a problem I am not able to solve. I want to make use of http cookies in flask. This is the code from documentation:

```
@app.route('/token/auth', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.json.get('username', None)
    password = request.json.get('password', None)
    if username != 'test' or password != 'test':
        return jsonify({'login': False}), 401

    # Create the tokens we will be sending back to the user
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=username)

    # Set the JWT cookies in the response
    resp = jsonify({'login': True})
    set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
    set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
    return resp, 200
```

I use `flask_restx` which automatically turns the response into JSON, so that `jsonify` in the first example is not needed. However, still still need to jsonify it, because i can not use `set_access_cookie` on a dictionary. This results at the end in a nested response like this `jsonify(jsonify(x))`

```
@api.route("/login")
class UserLogin(Resource):
    def post(self):
        """Allows a new user to login with his email and password"""

        email = request.get_json()["email"]
        password = request.get_json()["password"]

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).one_or_none()

        if user is None:
            return {"message": "user does not exist"}, 404

        user = user.format()
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(pw_hash=user["password"], password=password):

            if user["active"]:
                resp = jsonify({"login": True})
                access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
                refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user)
                set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
                set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
                return resp, 200
                # return (
                #     {"access_token": access_token, "refresh_token": refresh_token},
                #     200,
                # )

            else:
                return {"message": "User not activated"}, 400

        else:
            return {"message": "Wrong credentials"}, 401
```

This is the error: `TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable`

Any ideas how can I overcome this?

Comment: could you show result of `user.format()`?

Comment: solved it, but thank you very much for looking at it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve it like this:

```
data = dict(login=True)
resp = make_response(jsonify(**data), 200)
access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user)
set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
return resp
```